# Recursive VS Nonrecursive for binary tree traversal

Tags: binary-tree

What is the differences between Recursive VS Nonrecursive for binary tree traversal?

Which one is best for a large tree and Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Recursive functions are simpler to implement since you only have to care about a node, they use the stack to store the state for each call.

Non-recursive functions have a lot less stack usage but require you to store a list of all nodes for each level and can be far more complex than recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that a recursive way uses the call stack whereas an iterative way uses an explicit stack (the stack data structure). What this leads to are two things:
1) If it is a large tree, a recursive way can cause stack overflow.
2) With an iterative approach, you can stop somewhere in the middle of the traversal. In other words, you can implement something like a pre-order/in-order/post-order iterator with a stack. This can be useful in some cases.